# Fourier Transform of one variable in a two variable function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have a function in two variables, that satisfies the following PDE:
\begin{equation}
\frac{x-x_0}{x-x_1}\Psi_{xx}+\Psi_{yy}=0
\end{equation}

Initially I did use Fourier series
\begin{equation*}
\Psi=‎ \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_k(x) e^{iky}dy, 0 \leq y \leq 2 \pi
\end{equation*}

and obtained the following ODE
\begin{equation}
\frac{x-x_0}{x-x_1}\Psi_{xx}-k^2 \Psi=0
\end{equation}
However, this limits k to a discrete set, but in my case it needs to be any real number, so 
my Professor adviced me to use Fourier Transform on y, and obtain a function in terms of x and k, which should give me exactly same ODE as a result, yet k will be a real number.

My attempt:
Using the Fourier Transform
\begin{equation*}
\Psi=‎ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\Psi}(y) e^{2 \pi ik xy}dy, \ -\infty < y < \infty
\end{equation*}

However, I am not able to obtain the same ODE as before (Which I need specifically). I am not so familiar with Fourier Transforms, and I do not understand what mistake am I making. Any advice would be highly appriciated. Thank you!

Comment: The Fourier series is something you do to a periodic function, so if you use Fourier series then the solutions you get will all be periodic.

Comment: Do you know that $F(\phi') = 2 \pi i k F(\phi)$, where $F(\phi)$ is he Fourier transform of $\phi$ (using your convention) and $k$ is the Fourier variable?

Comment: This is how I would define things:
$$
\Psi(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \widehat\Psi(x,k)e^{2\pi i k x y}dk.
$$

Comment: If I define things in this way:\begin{equation*}
\Psi(x,y)=‎ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\Psi}(x,k) e^{2\pi ik xy}dk, \ -\infty < y < \infty,  k \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}then I do not get required ODE: \begin{equation}
\frac{x-x_0}{x-x_1}\Psi_{xx}-k^2 \Psi=0
\end{equation}, as when I derivate wrt y twice, I get some extra things, while I only need $-k^2 \Psi$. If I could define \begin{equation} \Psi(x,y)=‎ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\Psi}(x,k) e^{iky}dk \end{equation} that would be good, yet then it is not a Fourier Transform, so I am not sure what to do.